# Set String[] with variable length (as many element as are put in)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an string[] that I don't know what the length of it is going to be, currently I initialize like this just so I could put in my object, but I run into problems with this when I try to use it

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
```

How can i set the the length to mutable?

Thanks

**EDIT**

So I have a string[] and a string[][] and it works like this

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
String[][] dayMeals = new String[10][10];
```

I get my object and then add it like this

```
myArray[count] = item;
```

and then once i have all the items for that part I do this.

```
dayMeals[arrayCount] = myArray;
//then I reset myArray for the next set
myArray = new String[10];
```

And I am having trouble with ArrayLists setting it up like this.

Comment: what is the problem when you run it?

Comment: @GauravVarma I am using this array to set up a list view and I end up with extra cells, and null data

Comment: can you paste that code.. would suggest to initialize the string array according to the size of your list

Comment: @GauravVarma but I am adding parts of an xml doc to this array and I don't always know how many things will be added

Comment: In addition the the linked answer, uou can use Arrays.copyOf to resize your array, but I would rather use an ArrayList or similar

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)

Comment: see the simplest answer to your question is to use an ArrayList. But if you paste your code, then I can suggest appropriately.

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList? that way you can set the initial capacity and when it fills up it can dynamically resize the array?

Comment: so both variables needs to be array? otherwise you can use an ArrayList of ArrayList for the second one

Comment: @GauravVarma not quite sure what u mean?

Comment: can't answer as the ques is closed. You need something like this   List<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<List<String>> dayMeals = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

Comment: @GauravVarma the problem comes up as I am using `onProgressUpdate` which adds this takes  what every you have and then adds on [], are you familiar with `onProgressUpdate`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with onProgressUpdate.. although you can convert String array to ArrayList and vice versa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66699/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-gaurav-varma).